# Ole db connector for Mysql

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssis

I have remote machine with ip 192.X.X.X and am connecting it using putty(SSH) after login i was connecting to mysql using local host 127.0.0.1 and its working fine.

I was also able to mysql using mysql work bench using the option standard tcp/ip over SSH

currently am using SSIS 2012 is there any way we can connect to this mysql(which is in remote machine) using any connector..I tried oledb and odbc but not able to connect

Can any one help me on this...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where were you connecting to mysql from using 127.0.0.1? did you establish an ssh tunnel? Where is SSIS running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to connect to a mysql database (on a different server) for use with an SSIS 2012 package using an SSH session.

- First, install the mysql drivers if not already.  They can be found here:

[mysql official drivers](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

- Set up your SSH session.
- Set up port forwarding. Either do a remote forward (Set local_port: 3306, remote_host: yourmysqlservername_or_ip, remote_port: 3306 ) or a local forward (Set port: 3306, host: localhost, remote port: 3306).
- Log in to your server with the SSH session you just created.

[The preceding 3 steps taken from this link about using SSH with mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-and-ssh.html)

- Next, you will set up a data source (system DSN) from within the ODBC data source administrator (Installed along with the drivers hopefully, example shown in the following link).  This data source is what will then show up in your Connection manager list in SSIS.  **During this setup, you will put in 'localhost' as the server name rather than the actual server name, since you are using an SSH session and port forwarding.**

[Example DSN sestup](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/mysql-odbc.html)

- Finally, when you create a new connection in your SSIS package, choose an odbc connection and the data source name you just set up should show up in the list of data source names.